murder mystery television show in the 80s / 90s
There was a murder mystery television show back in the 80s and/or 90s that I am trying to remember the name of.
Things I remember:  

The detective/P.I. was an older gentleman  
I seem to recall he often wore a powder blue suit  
The show usually aired either before or after Murder She Wrote  
I can't remember for sure, but he may have appeared on Murder She Wrote once or twice.  

I know its not a lot to go on.

The only show that crossed over with Murder She Wrote was Magnum P I, and I'm pretty certain it's not the show you're talking about.

Did it air on the same channel? Remington Steele is another possibility.

Sounds like Matlock to me. Ran from 1986 to 1992 on NBC, then from 1992 to 1995 on ABC.
IMDb - Wikipedia


Ben Matlock is a very expensive criminal defense attorney who charges $100,000 to take a case. Fortunately, he's worth every penny as he and his associates defend his clients by finding the real killer.


Both are NBC and ABC are different networks than Murder (CBS), which would preclude any crossover episodes.

@JohnP: True, but the crossover seems to be a rather tenuous memory. Matlock had a crossover with Diagnosis: Murder, which was itself a spinoff of Matlock. (And D:M was on CBS, so a cross-network crossover isn't out of the question.)

True, which is why I suggested Remington Steele, but I'm not aware of any actual crossover episodes between networks.

YES!  Matlock!  Thank you!

It's practically a shot in the dark, but I think you may be looking for this TV Series. 
http://www.bigw.com.au/media/BIGW/Product/300x300/AID119062_0_med_v1_m56577569851463614.jpg

The Law & Harry McGraw is an American TV series that ran on CBS from September 27, 1987 to February 10, 1988. It is a spin-off
  from the mystery series Murder, She Wrote.

Full Wikipedia link here
This show starred Jerry Orbach, who portrays Harry McGraw, a recurring character from Murder, She Wrote. He was an old-school private investigator. After the unsuccess of his spin-off, he returned to play his character on Murder, She Wrote.
I am not sure if your description fits the main character, I am not sure if his suit can be counted as powder blue, as you stated. But I think that, judging by the details you gave, is a valid guess. Hope it can help you. :) 

Thank you very much for the attempt!  @Wrathchild hit it with Matlock.
