# Television crossover episodes between networks?

Tags: character, spin-off, crossovers

It can be somewhat common among spinoff series or when cross promotion is desired, for characters from one series to appear in episodes of another series. This has most recently been seen in some of the Law and Order episodes, and in various episodes of the NCIS and CSI family of series.

As noted in some of the comments in [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17258/murder-mystery-television-show-in-the-80s-90s), there have been a few cases of spinoff series appearing on other networks. I'm interested in finding out if there have been instances of character crossover in currently running episodes on competing networks? (Just as an example, members of the cast of Bones (Fox) appearing on CSI (CBS).)

Comment: It can get even more confusing if one lives outside of the US.  E.g. here in Canada, two closely related American shows could be bought by two different networks.  When it happens in the US, the networks have already agreed to it and planned it; when it happens here, it's by accident, and it's not obvious that the networks even want to advertise it as a crossover.  And worse, two related episodes could be aired in the wrong order.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia has some information about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_crossover#Television_series).

For instance, Detective John Munch from *Homicide: Life on the Street* (NBC) appeared in an episode of *The X Files* (FOX).

It's rare, but it happens.

Comment: Also Arrested Development, also The Wire. There was a time when it became a game to spot John Munch.

Answer (score 5):

I hate to send you to a website, but there is a master list of crossover appearances maintained at [Poobala](http://poobala.com/crossoverlist.html).  The site is physically elderly, to the extent that it uses frames, and it last had a major update in January 2012, but it is quite comprehensive.  There are so many crossovers listed that it would be futility to copy them all over here.  The aforementioned Munch appearances are all part of a massive crossover grouping which is all the dream of the autistic child at the end of St. Elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if OP meant that Bones interlinked characters/episodes with the tv show Crossing Jordan, I wasn't aware of crossovers with CSI but maybe I missed them.

Not sure if this counts but Joss Whedon's two shows Buffy and Angel were written in the same universe however at a later time Angel was moved to another television network. This is why there stopped being characters obviously inter-written between the shows unless they'd stopped being regular characters on their main show. There is one instance where they got around this Angel season 5 episode 20 where they indicate that Buffy is in the area and a blond girl is seen leaving the club, it's indicated that this is Buffy however Sarah Michelle Gellar was no longer interested in playing the character. All the links of crossovers are listed here http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Buffy_The_Vampire_Slayer_and_Angel_crossover_episodes.

Can't think of any others immediately but i'll include them as I think of them.

Answer (score 2):

**I'm interested in finding out if there have been instances of character crossover in currently running episodes on competing networks?**

If you count streaming services are competing for networks too then I will count *Crisis on Infinite Earths*

**In this crossover we have, CW network running shows;**

Supergirl (Originally CBS in seaosn 1)

The Flash

Batwoman

Arrow

Legends of Tomorrow

Black Lightning ( was not part of Arrowverse franchise before)

Freedom Fighters: The Ray (CW Seed)

**Canceled or long over old franchises from CW**

Smallville

**Canceled or long over old franchises, not from CW:**

Constantine (TV series)- NBC orginally (but later merged with arrowverse)

The Flash (1990 TV series) - CBS

Birds of Prey (TV series) - The WB

Tim Burton's Batman Movies

Batman (TV series) - ABC

Superman Returns

**Still running shows from non-CW streaming services:**

Titans - DC Universe

Lucifer - Netflix (originally fox)

Comment: Where does Gotham fit into this multi-universe mess?

Comment: @Jeeped nowhere

Comment: I'm thankful for response but confused. Did you mean to say that Gotham has no place in any universe or some other opinion?

Comment: @Jeeped I believe Ankit is saying that Gotham does not crossover with any of the other DC series.

Comment: *Batman* (1966) crossed over with *Green Hornet* (1966) in the *Batman* episodes "A Piece of the Action" and "Batman's Satisfaction".