# Do any crossover episodes of narrative shows on streaming services exist?

Tags: analysis, crossovers

Crossover episodes have long-been a staple of network TV that seemed to [peak in the 1990s](https://www.vulture.com/2016/03/crossover-episodes-tv.html)  (*Golden Girls* and *Empty Nest* on NBC in the ‘90s, CSI crossovers on CBS in the ‘00s, *Scandal* and *How to Get Away with Murder* on ABC in the ‘10s are among many other examples).

Crossover episodes have also occurred on cable TV, with *The Walking Dead* and *Fear the Walking Dead* on AMC and superhero shows on the CW.

But crossover episodes seems to be a strategy largely regulated to shows that air live / on network TV (and sometimes, rarely, [between networks](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17270/television-crossover-episodes-between-networks)).

All that said, are there any examples of crossover episodes on narrative series (not [reality shows](https://ew.com/tv/2018/06/29/nailed-it-queer-eye-crossover-episode-video/?amp=true)) that originated on streaming services like Hulu or Netflix?

Comment: Is there a crossover between *Walking Dead* and *Fear the walking dead*? I know that Morgan went from left one show to become a regular character of the other one, but not a crossover.

Comment: The CW is not a cable TV network.

Comment: are you looking only for streaming services' original programming? or any show that included in streaming services?

Comment: The new live action __[Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery#Franchise_expansion)__ shows on __CBS All Access__ are all interconnected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are the [Marvel series on Netflix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel%27s_Netflix_television_series):

The protagonists from *Daredevil*, *Jessica Jones*, *Luke Cage* and *Iron Fist* join together on *The Defenders*, *The Punisher* spun off from *Daredevil* and they all share multiple side characters. And of course they all belong to and reference the greater [Marvel Cinematic Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe).

Comment: There's all the ABC stuff too - they all tie through the movies, with Disney now picking up the pieces - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Television

Comment: Can we really consider whole different series with characters from multiple other series acting together as **crossover**?